# Bash shell variable loses scope

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to implement a plugin called homebridge-garagedoor-command for HomeBridge on a RaspberryPi which controls my garage doors. The plugin requires scripts for opening, closing and checking the status of the door. The way I have implemented it is to write python scripts, then a bash script which the plugin runs to call the python script. After running the python script (which simply switches a relay in the case of opening and closing the door) the script must return OPEN, CLOSED, CLOSING or OPENING. For the open and close commands that is simply:

```
echo CLOSING
```

or

```
echo OPENING
```

However, for checking the status of the door, I need the python script to return a value (I guess a 1 or a 0) depending on whether the door is open or closed. I am able to run the bash script and get a valid response (OPEN or CLOSED), but once the plugin runs the script, it always reports the door as being OPEN, which is the value of 0. It seems that once python passes the 1 or 0 to the bash script, the variable goes out of scope before (or during???) the compare operation in the if/else of the bash script.

My code for the python script is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
exitcode = GPIO.input(6)
GPIO.cleanup()
if exitcode == 1:
        sys.exit(1)
else:
        sys.exit(0)
```

The code for my bash script is:

```
python ~/.homebridge/scripts/stateleft.py
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
        echo "CLOSED"
else
        echo "OPEN"
fi
```

Like I say, the script(s) work fine when I run them manually, but as soon as the plugin tries to check the state, it always reports as OPEN. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct, it works like this:

```
Homebridge calls plugin bash script
    plugin bash calls python
        python does exit 1 or 0
    plugin tells OPEN or CLOSE
Homebridge thinks it's open
```

Correct?

If so, it's because the plugin does always exit with 0 because you don't tell otherwise. Change it to

```
python ~/.homebridge/scripts/stateleft.py
exitcode=$?
if [ $exitcode -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "CLOSED"
else
    echo "OPEN"
fi
exit $exitcode
```

But why not call the python script itself as the plugin? Why the bash in between?

Comment: The script, whether you run the python directly or a bash has to return the actual word CLOSED or OPEN, not the vallue of $exitcode. In any case, the problem was that for some reason $exitcode was always zero, so what you have suggested would echo OPEN and return 0 in every case.

Comment: So the problem was lying in the fact that you didn't run the script but sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. I noticed that while trying to fix this in a number of different ways, I was calling my bash script as 'sudo' in my config.json file. After I removed 'sudo' the script works as intended.

config.json was configured like this:

```
{
  "accessory": "GarageCommand",
  "name": "Left Door",
  "open": "./scripts/openleft.sh",
  "close": "./scripts/closeleft.sh",
  "state": "sudo ./scripts/stateleft.sh",
  "status_update_delay": 15,
  "poll_state_delay": 20
},
```

And now corrected looks like this:

```
{
  "accessory": "GarageCommand",
  "name": "Left Door",
  "open": "./scripts/openleft.sh",
  "close": "./scripts/closeleft.sh",
  "state": "./scripts/stateleft.sh",
  "status_update_delay": 15,
  "poll_state_delay": 20
},
```